# Call Mac OS X Get Info dialog from Java?

Tags: java, macos

Is it possible to call get info dialog in mac os for a specific file in Java?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no Java API that does that, but you can execute external programs so perhaps you could write some sort of AppleScript (or whatever they call it) and execute that?

Comment: If you Google you'll find a number of AppleScript files that do exactly what you want.